# How to distribute task among multiple thread in openmp?

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I want to distribute task among four threads using Openmp. I have 20x20 matrix and task should be equally distributed among four thread, following program giving wrong result. I think it need changing parameter in for loop, can any one help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<omp.h>
    #include "head.h"
    //int sum=0;
    int c[20][20];
    //#include<conio.h>
        int main(void) {
            int A[20][20],B[20][20],C[20][20];
            int i;
            static int j,e;
            static sum=0;
            FILE *fp;
            unsigned long long a,b,c,d;

            int threadno;
            fp=fopen("m2.txt","w");
            //    printf("\n%d \n",h[20][20]);
                #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,d)
            {
            threadno=omp_get_thread_num();

            if(threadno==0)
            {       
                for (i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                for (j=0;j<5;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=i*j;
                    B[i][j]=i*j;
                }
                }

                for (i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                for (j=0;j<5;j++)
                {
                    for (e=0;e<5;e++)
                    {
                    sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                            C[i][j]=sum;
                    }
                }
                }
            }

            else if(threadno==1)
            {   
                for (i=5;i<10;i++)
                {
                for (j=5;j<10;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=i*j;
                    B[i][j]=i*j;
                }
                }

                for (i=5;i<10;i++)
                {
                for (j=5;j<10;j++)
                {
                    for (e=5;e<10;e++)
                    {
                    sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                            C[i][j]=sum;
                    }
                }
                }
            }


            else if(threadno==2)
            {   
                for (i=10;i<15;i++)
                {
                for (j=10;j<15;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=i*j;
                    B[i][j]=i*j;
                }
                }

                for (i=10;i<15;i++)
                {
                for (j=10;j<15;j++)
                {
                    for (e=10;e<15;e++)
                    {
                    sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                            C[i][j]=sum;
                    }
                }
                }
            }

            else if(threadno==3)
            {   
                for (i=15;i<20;i++)
                {
                for (j=15;j<20;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=i*j;
                    B[i][j]=i*j;
                }
                }

                for (i=15;i<20;i++)
                {
                for (j=15;j<20;j++)
                {
                    for (e=15;e<20;e++)
                    {
                    sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                            C[i][j]=sum;
                    }
                }
                }
            }       

            for (i=0;i<20;i++){
                for (j=0;j<20;j++) {
                    fprintf(fp,"%d \t",C[i][j]);
                }
            }
    }
    fclose(fp); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread is only producing 25 values around the diagonal.  Is that what you intended?  Your matrix has 400 entries, but you are only actually initializing 4*25 = 100 of them, so the printout at the end is going to be mostly garbage except around the diagonal.

All of your threads are also accessing the variable `sum` without any locking/synchronization, so the values you read out of sum are completely non-deterministic.

If you really intended to write a matrix*matrix multiply: then you should first write the triply-nested loop you intended to write.  Perhaps something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {
    for (int e=0; e<20; e++) {
      // some work
    }
  }
}
```

Then divide up the outermost loop between the 4 threads:

```
for (int i = 5*omp_get_thread_num(); i < 5*(omp_get_thread_num()+1); i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {
    ...
```

Or even better have openMP divide the work for you.  (I am not an openMP expert but I think this is how you do it.)

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp for
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++) {
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.  Change the floats to ints.

```
void matrix_mult_scalar_openmp(const float*A , const float* B, float* C, const int N, const int M, const int K) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            float tmp = 0;
            for(int l=0; l<M; l++) {
                tmp += A[M*i+l]*B[K*l+j];
            }
            C[K*i + j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I must have to do this using 4 threads, as per wandering login it works using single for loop, but I want to device task among 4 thread.I made the changes as per Raxman, some code is unchanges because I have to use 4 threads here.
My modified code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include "head.h"
//int sum=0;
int c[20][20];
//#include<conio.h>
    int main(void) {
        int A[20][20],B[20][20],C[20][20];
        int i;
        static int j,e;
        int sum;
        FILE *fp;
        unsigned long long a,b,c,d;

        int threadno;
        fp=fopen("m2.txt","w");
         for (i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
            for (j=0;j<20;j++)
            {
                A[i][j]=i*j;
                B[i][j]=i*j;
            }
            }
        //    printf("\n%d \n",h[20][20]);
            #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,d)
        {
        threadno=omp_get_thread_num();



        if(threadno==0)
        {       


            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
            for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                sum=0;
                for (e=0;e<5;e++)
                {
                sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
//                          C[i][j]=sum;
                }
             C[i][j]=sum;
            }
            }
        }

        else if(threadno==1)
        {   
    /*      for (i=5;i<10;i++)
            {
            for (j=5;j<10;j++)
            {
                A[i][j]=i*j;
                B[i][j]=i*j;
            }
            }*/

            for (i=5;i<10;i++)
            {
            for (j=5;j<10;j++)
            {
                sum=0;
                for (e=5;e<10;e++)
                {
                sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                //        C[i][j]=sum;
                }
             C[i][j]=sum;
            }
            }
        }


        else if(threadno==2)
        {   
          /*  for (i=10;i<15;i++)
            {
            for (j=10;j<15;j++)
            {
                A[i][j]=i*j;
                B[i][j]=i*j;
            }
            }*/

            for (i=10;i<15;i++)
            {
            for (j=10;j<15;j++)
            {
                sum=0;
                for (e=10;e<15;e++)
                {
                sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                    }
             C[i][j]=sum;
            }
            }
        }

        else if(threadno==3)
        {   
        /*    for (i=15;i<20;i++)
            {
            for (j=15;j<20;j++)
            {
                A[i][j]=i*j;
                B[i][j]=i*j;
            }
            }*/

            for (i=15;i<20;i++)
            {
            for (j=15;j<20;j++)
            {
                sum=0;
                for (e=15;e<20;e++)
                {
                sum+=A[i][e]*B[e][j];
                        //C[i][j]=sum;
                }
             C[i][j]=sum;
            }
            }
        }       

        for (i=0;i<20;i++){
            for (j=0;j<20;j++) {
                fprintf(fp,"%d \t",C[i][j]);
            }
        }
}
fclose(fp); 
}
```